# What does the symbol after someone's name mean in the Snapchat app?

Tags: snapchat

In the Snapchat app, I'm not really sure what this symbol after the name means.

[image]

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon is a horoscope icon. I believe it happens when you enter your birthday into Snapchat it adds the corresponding horoscope icon.

- ♒ Aquarius
- ♓ Pisces
- ♈ Aries
- ♉ Taurus
- ♊ Gemini
- ♋ Cancer
- ♌ Leo
- ♍ Virgo
- ♎ Libra
- ♏ Scorpio
- ♐ Sagittarius
- ♑ Capricorn

---

Note: refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_sign) for the alternative if the emoji is rendered correctly.